# Unable to repeat function in else statement getting error 'str' object not callable

Tags: python, function, error-handling, python-3.5

So i have looked at different posts where people posted about the same error code and tried some different modifications of my code by making some variables global.

```
def SchoolYear():
 os.system('clear')
 print('Please enter Which Year you are in School. EX.) 11th or Senior')
 print('')
 global SchoolYear
 SchoolYear = input('Please enter the class: ')
 if SchoolYear in ('11th', '12th', '10th', '9th', 'Senior', 'senior', 'freshman', 'Freshman', 'sophomore', 'Sopomore', 'junior', 'Junior' ):
    print('Good Job')
 else:
    print("Invalid Entry Please Try again...")
    print('')
    SchoolYear()
```

All i want the code to de is if it doesnt match my critia then to repeat the same function but i contiously get the error code 'str' object not callable

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: you are redefining the type of SchoolYear in the line `SchoolYear = input('Please enter the class: ')`, try renaming it

Comment: also, why are you using the same name for the method and the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is confusing the `SchoolYear` variable name with the `SchoolYear` function name. Change the name of the function or the variable and it will work:

```
def SchoolYearFunc():
    os.system('clear')
    print('Please enter Which Year you are in School. EX.) 11th or Senior')
    print('')
    global SchoolYear
    SchoolYear = input('Please enter the class: ')
    if SchoolYear in ('11th', '12th', '10th', '9th', 'Senior', 'senior', 'freshman', 'Freshman', 'sophomore', 'Sopomore', 'junior', 'Junior' ):
        print('Good Job')
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry Please Try again...")
        print('')
        SchoolYearFunc()
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you i cant believe i didnt think of that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "you entered", var

if var in ['11th', '12th', '10th', '9th', 'Senior', 'senior', 'freshman', 'Freshman', 'sophomore', 'Sopomore', 'junior', 'Junior']:
    print('Good Job')
 else:
    print("Invalid Entry Please Try again...")
```

is there a reason you want to enclose the above functionality inside a class?